# What is the most efficient way to cross the ocean?

Tags: a-valley-without-wind

So I am at a point where I have to cross the ocean to be able to continue. I got some Illari Scrolls that place a buoy on a tile, but it only clears 1 ocean tile from the storm.

Is there a less grindy way to cross the ocean? Because those buoy cost like 6k each and I have 4 tiles to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Across the World, there are some Deep Sea Ports.
One has to free them from the storm to be able to board a ship which then can go over the deep ocean and very stormy areas.

Answer (score 0):

Acid Gills (For Underwater Exploration)

> If you're planning on venturing into the ocean or the ocean shallows,
>   you're going to need acid gills in order to breathe underwater as well
>   as to not be harmed by the acid that normally eats away at your
>   health. Some of the more advanced acid gills enchants actually make
>   you a better swimmer as well, so you're not all sluggish in the water
>   -- if you want to have any hope of dodging some of the viciously fast underwater denizens, you'll need these more advanced enchants. The
>   oceans are truly one of the more dangerous parts of Environ! If you're
>   having trouble finding this enchant type by grabbing Enchant Charges
>   or by searching Stashes, it can be bought in the Opal Store for 4000
>   shards.

More info about useful items on the [Arcengames Wiki](http://www.arcengames.com/mediawiki/index.php?title=AVWW_-_How_Do_I_Know_If_I%27m_Prepared_For_An_Expedition?)

Comment: Sorry, but thats wrong.